# How to unsync two folders?

Tags: directory, rsync

I have Ubuntu One and Dropbox folders synced. Now when Ubuntu One is shutting down, I want to delete U1 folder so it does not use space unnecessary.
The problem is that if I delete U1 folder, Dropbox folder will be deleted to, because I don't know how to unsync them.

I synced them using Grsync, GUI for rsync. 
I first deleted profiles form grsync, but folders was still synced. Then I deleted grsync itself, and .grsync folder from HOME, and that did not help.

**What should I do? Is it safe to delete rsync like workaround?**

EDIT: I think I did not explained how dirs are synced. U1 dir is like my working dir, with all sort of projects. DB dir is synced with U1 dir in way, that everything I save/delete to/from U1 is saved/deleted to/from DB dir. If I make any file in DB it will be auto deleted because there is no copy of that file in U1 dir.

Thanks in advance, and sorry form my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the files from your system to another directory.

Then delete the U1 program from Ubuntu Software Center and turn off other synch tools if you use them. That will kill the synching and free up your directory you used for synching without the risk of loosing data.

Comment: This helped. I first copied my files to safe location, then deleted U1 directory, and now my Dropbox folder is free (not synced anymore).It's not really an answer, it's workaround, but thanks anyway.